# JSON string stored in SqlLite -- how to escape single and double quotes

Tags: ruby, json, sqlite, escaping

I need to store the following json message in sqlite. However I am unable to do it since my input message has  single quotes in it. Although the escaping of double quotes are handled, the single quote still throws an error. How can this be solved? The input message is as follows..

```
'{
"request" : [
    {
        "name" : "test",
        "number" : "8",
        "data" : {
            "message" : "This is a test 'messa'ge "
        }
    }
],

"data1" : {
    "data2" : 1,
    "data3" : "Hello"
},

"message1" : "tes't example"
}'
```

Comment: CL shouldn't have closed this, the "dup" had nothing to do with working with SQLite.

Comment: @muistooshort The only problem actually shown in the question is with Ruby quoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string will cause a ruby syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
            "message" : "This is a test 'messa'ge "
```

To create your string, you can use:

1. **%q[ ]**, which is equivalent to single quotes.
2. **%Q[ ]**, which is equivalent to double quotes.

You can use any character as the delimiter, eg.

```
%q|Dave's head is small.|

%q{Dave's head is small.}

%q=Dave's head is small.=
```

So you can create your string error free, like this:

```
your_string =  %q[{
    "request" : [
        {
            "name" : "test",
            "number" : "8",
            "data" : {
                "message" : "This is a test 'messa'ge "
            }
        }
    ],

    "data1" : {
        "data2" : 1,
        "data3" : "Hello"
    },

    "message1" : "tes't example"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ins = db.prepare('insert into table_name (column_name) values (?)')
ins.execute(your_string)
```